# How to implement voice & video chat

Tags: android, video, chat, voip

I am working on a android application in which i have to implement peer to peer voice chat. I found in android this is possible in API level 12 or above because Google added `android.net.rtp` package in API level 12. By using this package we can implement peer to peer voice chat and video chat. But I need to implement this for API level 8. Now my questions are:

1. How i can implement this peer to peer voice chat for API level 8.
2. Is Jmf (java media framework) is compatible with android.
3. Is any other API available for android to implement this idea.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest have a look at PJSIP opensource SIP stack. It isn't officially ported to Android, but some people have succeeded in using it on Android and have posted patches too.

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

The "csipsimple" project seems to be under active development.

http://sipdroid.org/ might be helpful too.

HTH

Comment: I want to use RTP/RTCP. so please help me from scratch.

Comment: Implementation of RTP/RTCP protocol stack is a big task. PJSIP has implementation of RTP/RTCP for their use with VoIP, so if you are looking for an API, I'd still recommend PJSIP with JNI as the way to go. They have great documentation and is actively supported.

Comment: @KapilPendse I am looking for a workaround of Voice Chat over Bluetooth. Can you help me in that?

Answer (score -2):

Also f/oss is Linphone

Consider the reflections in **RFC 7081**, too

Possibly: tunnel your sip/rtp to overcome carrier inanities -- not merely the IPv4 flavor.

For additional inspiration:  http://SipSorcery.com , http://Anveo.com , prism-break , F-Droid